# Cannot update Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to update my Android Studio to the latest version. Right now I am running 1.0.1. I am a beginner in android programming. I started learning quite long ago but couldn't continue. Now I want to get back but the problem is that when I click update, it takes me to https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/studio/canary/latest which is the canary build. I want the dev channel version. I also have Dev Channel selected in the Updates settings. A little bit of help is much appreciable.

I am running on **Ubuntu 15.10. Intel i5-4430, 4GB RAM**.

Here's the Screenshots:
[Screenshot 1](http://image.prntscr.com/image/3df75d288cbe42f8be47289fc1bff359.png)
[Screenshot 2](http://image.prntscr.com/image/b0cc1313840b4c8997735f0c0fb5e286.png)

(Dosen't let me post pics or more than 2 links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the [latest dev versions](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/studio/dev) , but you should install the preview 2 version in the canary channel due to bug corrections (but it's possible that it introduce new bugs). If you don't want to take risks then install the Stable version (the dev channel list in the link has an stable version). It's important to note that you need to download all again because your Android Studio version is very old. Note that the 2.2 (preview) version comes with new features [like the new layout editor](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-editor).

Comment: Is it ok to use the canary one? I just have to start learning Android programming.

Comment: Yes it's OK, you have the latest features but also the newest bugs. The update frequency is about twice a month. If you are learning and like to have the cutting edge features (like the new layout editor for the "Constraint layout") then use it.

Comment: Thanks. I will get the Canary version. The new layout editor looks cool.

Answer (score 0):

Your version cannot be upgraded via a standard patch. You need to download the whole thing again. If you don't want the canary build you can always google where the stable channel downloads are located

Answer (score 0):

https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/studio/dev 
Grab the dev Version here. :) 
Also you can't download and install the update automatically, you'll have to download the zip, extract it and execute studio.sh